# send two multipart files(of type: .json and attachment) as request in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am not able to send two files as multipart request in http request along with header.

```js
const header = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': token,
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
      }),
    };

return this.httpClient.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/upload?, jsonfile, attachment, header));
```

but, I got below error: **Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 4.**

tried to add to form-data, also was trying to pass in one array but still was not able to get the solution.

Comment: You are using HttpClient incorrectly, this is what the error tells you. See the [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post) on which parameters you can use to perform a POST request with the HttpClient.